# Change EditText inputType after enter first character by user

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have an `EditText` like this in my xml file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/InputPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="رمز عبور"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

For some reason I want to change its inputType after user entered first Character. I try this way:

```
Pass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(start == 0){
                    Pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

But it does not work!
Is anybody there that know any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved to the best result by this one:

```
Pass.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            Pass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
Pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

To :

```
Pass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Hi bro, An issue, when I apply this solution and get edittext text after that, `Pass.getText().toString()` returned string missed first character!!! e.g. If I entered 123456 get text return 23456 ?!?!?!

Comment: @MAY3AM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318909/change-edittext-inputtype-after-enter-first-character-by-user/26319095#comment41303573_26319095 what's wrong with you ?

Comment: I mentioned you, this answer has a little buggy! first  time user fill the EditText, returned String Miss the first character, but when user fill it again, returned string is as well as user entered!

Comment: @MAY3AM I just tested it, work for me .. try to find the bug in your code/xml some where. proof : https://github.com/selmanon/EditTextSetTransformationMethod

Answer (score 0):

Inside the

> afterTextChanged

method, try to to the following :

```
  @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            System.out.println("Editable: "+s);
            if(s.getText().toString().length ==1)
               Pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        }
```

Comment: getText()  is undefined for the type of Editable!